# How can I generate a 5-dimensional multivariate normal

Tags: r

How can I generate a 5-dimensional multivariate normal with names (Y, X1, X2, Z1, Z2), and 5347 observations, with bilateral correlations

Correlations:

```
Y x1 x2 Z1 Z2
Y 1.0 0.2 0.1 0.35 0.0
x1 0.2 1.0 0.0 0.4 0.0
x2 0.1 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.4
Z1 0.35 0.4 0.0 1.0 0.6
Z2 0.0 0.0 0.4 0.6 1.0
```

I tried to generate matrix and mvtnorm and MASS package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvrnorm()` from `MASS` works fine for me (see code below). Having said this, if you input a correlation vs. covariance matrix the random variables output from the function will be on a different scale to the original data (i.e., each will be scaled to have unit variance).

If for some reason you can't compute the covariance matrix but you know your variables' standard deviations, [dayne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740796/generate-covariance-matrix-from-correlation-matrix) provides a way to get it from the correlation matrix.

```
library(MASS)

# Make covariance matrix. See note above re the implications of using a correlation matrix.
S = matrix(c(1.0, 0.2, 0.1, 0.35, 0.0,
             0.2, 1.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.0,
             0.1, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.4,
             0.35, 0.4, 0.0, 1.0, 0.6,
             0.0, 0.0, 0.4, 0.6, 1.0), ncol = 5)
colnames(S) = c("Y1", "X1", "X2", "Z1" ,"Z2")
rownames(S) = colnames(S)

# Make mean vector
mus = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); names(mus) = colnames(S)

# Generate 5347 observations
obs = mvrnorm(n = 5347, mu = mus, Sigma = S)
head(obs)
```

Comment: ... with `empirical = TRUE` to get same correlation

Comment: Happy to help. If it solved your problem would you mind accepting the answer (just click the "tick" next to where you up/down-vote)?

Comment: Thanks. I did. I tried to solve it and had no clue how to transform cor matrix to covariance.

Comment: Sorry, just read the question more carefully and didn't pick up on the fact that you were inputting a correlation vs. covariance matrix. I've updated my answer with some caveats, and there's an answer on how to get covariance from correlation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740796/generate-covariance-matrix-from-correlation-matrix. You need to know the standard deviations of your variables though.